# PDF.js remove contextual information on print

Tags: javascript, pdf, web, pdf.js

Upon printing a file through the PDF.js printer, conxtectual information gets added to the page to be printed. Things like url, date, ... (see image)

How do I remove this metadata and just print the pdf file itself?

[image: How to remove the metadata?]